# html code to three image over one background image at different position

Tags: html, css

I am using multiple div in html code.Each div will hold image of 1600*750. Inside each div i have fixed image.These image will repeat on each multiple div I call these image as class on each div.
My first image is 218*73
My second image is 774*209
My third is 127*37

I want to fix my first image position at 137*88 of my background div image.
second image at 655*339 of background div image.
third image at 708*670 of background div image.

I don't want to use body to fix as background image as I Have multiple div with three fix image on all div.

Can any one tell how to fix these position with css using class for multiple div.
Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My page</title> 
<title>jQuery Parallax Plugin Demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sd.css" />

</head>

    <body>
 <div id="a"> 
    <div id="first" >
       <div class="c d" >

       This is my first div to display image.





   </div>-->


 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 body{
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

div {
    -webkit-perspective: 500px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    perspective: 500px;
}


#first{
    width: 100%;
 }


#first{

    background:url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
     perspective: 1px;

}
#first .d{
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;

    width:=655px;
    height:339px;
    background: url('images/Logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}
#first .c{
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;

    width:=137px;
    height:88px;
    background: url('images/big_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}
 #first .e{
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: 708px;
     overflow-y: 670px;

    background: url('images/big_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows an example with your images sizes and positions:

```css
body {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1600x750');
}
.first {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/218x73');
    border:1px dashed #000;
    display:block;
    height:73px;
    left:137px;
    position:absolute;
    top:88px;
    width:218px;
}
.second {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/774x209');
    border:1px dashed #000;
    display:block;
    height:209px;
    left:655px;
    position:absolute;
    top:339px;
    width:774px;
}
.third {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/127x37');
    border:1px dashed #000;
    display:block;
    height:37px;
    left:708px;
    position:absolute;
    top:670px;
    width:127px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but i have multiple div having different image all of with 1600*750 and three fixed image to apply as foreground and at same position on all background image on multiple div.so I used class to call all three image on multiple div,so I can't use it as background image

Answer (score 0):

can you create a snippet ? the div are not closed, first and c div are within div "a" ?

```
<div id="a"> 
<div id="first" >
   <div class="c d" >

   This is my first div to display image.
```